# Matching Multiple Columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 60 columns in one table and 60 columns in another table and in the third table it should display matching records as 1 and unmatch records as 0. I am able to do with one column only but multiple columns, facing problem. Note: All the matched and unmatched records should display in the third table all at a time.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is your 3rd table showing expected results, or results you are currently getting?  What is the formula you are currently using?

Comment: Why column 1 in the row corresponding to Sweets displaying 0, and apples is displaying 1?

Answer (score 1):

It should simply be a matter of pointing at one cell and and saying equal to another cell then the copy the formula down and right as far as needed.  If you select the cells with the mouse after starting to enter the formula in the cell, excel should add in the worksheet name for you.  This will give you TRUE/FALSE results.  In order to change them to 1 or 0 simply put the true or false result through a math operation that will not change the value. --, *1, +0, /1 all work.  The following is a formula you could use:

```
=--(A3=E3)
```

Remember to edit your cell reference to suit your data:

[image: poc]